# Is it possible to get all the element on a web page using html package

Tags: flutter

I am making a flutter webscrawler app and I am required to get all the element on a web page(from body and rest of it)This is what I have done so far.

```
  var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://www.dr.com.tr/');
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var document = parse(response.body);
  // print(document.body?.text.trim()); Not working
   // print(document.body?.innerHtml);Not working
   // print(document.outerHtml)//not working
```

Answer (score 0):

user this.. html: ^0.15.0

```
import 'package:html/dom.dart';

var document = parse(response.body);
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("class you want to access");
var innerHtml = document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerHtml
//element.getElementsByTagName("element name")[0].innerHtml
```